# Removing all buttons on related lists across all page layouts through the metadata

Tags: page-layout, metadata, related-list, xml

I need to remove all buttons on related lists across all page layouts.  I work with the metadata as this is a package with releases, so ultimately, I need the changes reflected in the .layout files.

The problem with this is that the XML isn't boolean. The code to remove buttons from related lists looks like this

```
<excludeButtons>Merge</excludeButtons>
```

And as a whole:

```
<relatedLists>
    <excludeButtons>Merge</excludeButtons>
    <excludeButtons>NewContact</excludeButtons>
    <fields>NAME</fields>
    <fields>Messaging_Campaign__c</fields>
    <relatedList>Msg_Camp_Resp__c.Ad__c</relatedList>
</relatedLists>
```

If I had a list of every single button name, I could possibly add the `<excludeButtons>`line for every option on every layout, and have a script save and remove the options until it validates.  This is a horrible idea though.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?  I would like the process, in general, to be automatic but I'm not sure where to begin / how at all to do this without doing it manually.  Tips on how to get a list of button names, for example, would be a great start!

Comment: It's probably a lot more of a task than you may be up for, but it can be done. You could create a Java app to do this using a soap describe call for layouts. You'd have to call this for every object you want to remove the buttons for and return the button labels. Then you would need to iterate through all your .layouts that are for those objects and create the excludebuttons line with each of those labels in it. I'd personally JAR that bad boy and throw it in an ant script to run in continuous integration but I don't know what your setup is on that side.

Comment: @cricketlang we work with ant, so we could definitely write a script.  I don't understand how you can find the button labels in the first place.  I looked all over for them and couldn't find them.

Comment: Check out the documentation here. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describelayout_describelayoutresult.htm#i1426084

Comment: @cricketlang thank you! with that list, this shouldn't be too hard.